# Creating an annotation like Slf4j for my project

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, annotations, slf4j

I've been trying to replicate the @Slf4j annotation with my logger, I've looked around at guides and information online about using annotations, but can't figure out how to use annotations for THIS SPECIFIC purpose.

The Slf4j annotation creates a logger field in the annotated class:

```
@Slf4j
public class Person {
   public void doThing() {
      log.info("logged a message"); 
      //log doesn't need to be defined in this class or instantiated manually. 
      //The annotation automatically does:
      //Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Person.class);
   }
}
```

If I have my own logger with the same method getLogger(String) to instantiate the logger just like Slf4j, how could I create an annotation "@MyLogger" for example which will replicate Slf4j?

More info about the annotation:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging-with-lombok/

Could someone provide an example class creating this annotation for the below logger class? I'm really confused, cannot get this to work.

```
public class Logger {

    public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> test) {
        return new Logger(); //for test purpose (how logger should be inited)
    }

    public void info(String test) {
    }


}
```

Comment: This features uses [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) which is basically black magic with regards to the Java compiler to enable features that can't be done in regular Java (such as adding fields simply by having an annotation). Read up on Lombok. "Normal" Java can't do things like that.

Comment: Are you able to create a your own Slf4j annotation?

Answer (score 0):

`@Slf4j` annotation is built into Lombok, so you would need to [implement your own annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-custom-annotation).

However as you see it's not very simple, and you probably want to use a standard logging framework anyway.